# what would be the file size if I store all possible 64 bit double in it using Java?

Tags: java, file, memory

I would like to know what would be the size of file if I store all possible 64 bit double in it? I tried to write program to store all possible doubles into file, but it takes long time.

Comment: You should approach this question through theory, not through a program, as you should realize there would be very close to 2⁶⁴ × 8 bytes in the file - and that's a huge number of write operations. So ask yourself: why 2⁶⁴ numbers? And why "close to" and not "exactly"?

Comment: You mention time but don't actually ask about it. If you have 128EB of disk (see answer) and use a single generating process that inherently can write one disk at a time, and your disks write about 100MB/s (typical today), it will take about **30 thousand years** -- assuming the computer and disks last that long, as well as your source or supply of electricity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say "kilobyte" etc. we are literally meaning 1024 bytes. There's some confusion about sometimes people meaning 1000 bytes instead, but we're talking about the same order of magnitude. (I tend to prefer to use "kibibyte" for 1024 bytes to be specific, but that's another question.)

What's a byte? It's 8 bits. So your 64 bit double takes up 8 bytes. And how many different 64 bit doubles are there? Each bit is either a 0 or a 1, so overall you have 2<sup>64</sup> doubles, and so 2<sup>64</sup>*8 = 2<sup>67</sup> bytes to store.

A kilobyte is 2<sup>10</sup> bytes, so an exabyte is 2<sup>60</sup> bytes (this is over a million terabytes!). Therefore your file would take up at least 128 exabytes.

**Edit:** see the discussion in the comments - this analysis is incorrect, if you don't count positive/negative zero, infinity and NaN as "proper" doubles. There is 1 double that represents positive infinity, one double that represents negative infinity, and 2<sup>53</sup>-1 possible NaN values. (See e.g. [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/).) There's also 1 double that represents positive zero and 1 double that represents negative zero.

So depending on which of these you accept, you wouldn't need to store quite so many double values. However, 2<sup>53</sup>x8 = 2<sup>56</sup>, which is over 1000 times smaller than 2<sup>67</sup>, so you're still looking at 127.94 exabytes.

You might also complain that there are multiple ways of representing the same double (in the worst-case scenario, about 50 ways), but again you still have well over 20 exabytes, which is vastly more than your computer will be able to store.

Comment: The OP asked about *possible doubles*. Not all 64 bit combinations are legal doubles. So the answer to the question is *different* than the answer to "all possible longs", for example.

Comment: Sorry, which combinations are not legal? As far as I'm aware, Java uses 1 sign bit, 11 exponent bits, and 52 'mantissa' bits. I can't think of any combination of those that would lead to an illegal double...

Comment: Well, a large number of the combinations are NaN, which are not "possible doubles" and certainly should not be considered as either distinct  values or equal.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see how that could happen. Isn't (sign) x mantissa x 2^(exponent) always going to be a well-defined value? I can't see how you could e.g. divide by 0 to get an invalid number.

Is your point that you have duplicated values (i.e. different double representations of the same number)?

Comment: NaN is not a "well defined value". That's why It's called "Not a Number". That's why, for example, if you assign NaN to two variables and compare them, you don't get "true". And the double representation includes a positive and negative zero, negative and positive infinity, and a whole range of NaN.

Comment: Ah I see - I'd forgotten that there are conventions for when a double represents +-infinity or NaN instead of a "genuine" double.